# Select a row based on where have maximum by one column

Tags: sql

I have a table called **match_score** which have following data

| id | participant | round | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gabe | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | john | 1 | 90 |
| 3 | duff | 1 | 80 |
| 4 | vlad | 1 | 85 |
| 5 | gabe | 2 | 75 |
| 6 | john | 2 | 70 |

Let's just say that **round** `1` is the preliminary round and `2` is the final round

I want to rank the result based on the score and grouped by the `participant` , if I'm using some normal sql `group by participant` and `order by score desc`.

**vlad** are the 1st, **duff** 2nd and **gabe** 3rd, which one is wrong.

what i want is

1st **gabe** with 75 point in the final round

2nd **john** with 70 point in the final round

3rd **vlad** with 85 point in the preliminary round

4th **duff** with 80 point in the preliminary round

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using so many tags just to make sure the question will appear on the database enthusiast radar, so i'm adding another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
select 
  h.participant, 
  h.round, 
  h.score 
from 
  match_score h 
where 
  not exists (
    select 1 
    from 
      match_score t 
    where 
      t.participant = h.participantand t.round > h.round
  ) 
order by 
  h.round desc, 
  h.score desc;
```